# ASPX Session State null exception on Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, state, postback

I'm can't seem to get a Session Variable to read on postback, even with the simple code below:

Default.apsx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" 

Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" AutoPostBack="true" Text="Button" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

codebehind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            varcheck(Session["MyVar"].ToString());
        }
    }

    protected void varcheck(string checker)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(checker);
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string ret_val = "Return this on postback";
        Session["MyVar"] = ret_val; 

    }
}
```

I get:

```
An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_5mcbvlrk.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Am I missing something?  Shouldn't the Session variable be set on the click of the button and read on Postback?  Does it need to be set globally?

Comment: Stop using session please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because when you click on button it does not go directly to `Button1_Click` Event it goes from top to bottom so it loads the `Page_Load` first then it goes to the event so you should place a check

```
      if (IsPostBack && Session["MyVar"] != null)
        {
            varcheck(Session["MyVar"].ToString());
        }
```

that if `Session["MyVar"]` is not `null` because it will be null in first `postback` to it will not throw exception

**Edit 1**

if dont want to use session you can use static variable to store data

```
    public static string MyVar;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MyVar))
    {
        varcheck(MyVar);
    }
}
```

and you can set value on click like

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(MyVar))
      {
        MyVar= "Return this on postback";
        varcheck(MyVar);

      }

    }
```

Comment: So to get the actual value on postback, I'd technically have to do 2 postbacks?  Is there a better alternative to set a variable and read it properly on postback?

Comment: you can declare a static field to store data

Comment: So the same still applies - first postback, the static string is null, the second postback, the static string is the wanted value...I guess an alternative would be to do a javascript client-side postback with a string if I want to retrieve it on the current postback.  Is there a way to achieve this in pure codebehind?

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand the postback routine better, it makes more sense to me.  I ended up using a javascript __doPostBack method, it seems to work well enough.